# How to iterate through two lists which are dictionary values in parallel?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I need help to iterate through a data dictionary column called `'TimeO'` and `'TimeC'` in this function.

```
Data_Dict = {'TimeO': ['9:00:00', '10:00:00'] 'TimeC': ['14:00:00', '16:00:00']}
```

`x` should be values from `TimeO` and `y` should be values from `TimeC`.

I can't figure out how to iterate the values

```
def timed_duration():
        opening = datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')
        closing = datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S')
        sec =(closing-opening).total_seconds()
        hour = sec/3600
        return(hour)
timed_duration()
```

`x` and `y` should iterate through 400 records but I don't know what to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your data look like this:

```
Data_Dict = {'TimeO': ['9:00:00', '10:00:00'], 'TimeC': ['14:00:00', '16:00:00']}

def timed_duration(data_dict):
    hours = []  # create an empty list to store all the results
    for x, y in zip(data_dict['TimeO'], data_dict['TimeC']):
        opening = datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')
        closing = datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S')
        sec =(closing-opening).total_seconds()
        hour = sec/3600
        hours.append(hour)
    return hours  # no parenthesis in return

timed_duration(Data_Dict)
```

This will create a list called `hours` filled with the results of your function.
The `zip()` thingy allow you to iterate through both objects at the same time.